# partial fraction question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

> $ \frac{125x^{2}+x+3}{x^{2}(x-5)} =
> > \frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x^{2}}+\frac{C}{(x-5)} | * x^{2}(x-5)$
>
> $125x^{2}+x+3 = Ax(x-5) + B(x-5) + C (x^{2})$
>
> $125x^{2}+x+3 = A x^{2} - 5Ax + Bx -5B +Cx^{2}$
>
> $125x^{2}+x+3 = x^{2}(A+C) -x(A+B)-5B$
>
> $3 = -5B \Rightarrow B = \frac{-3}{5}$
>
> $-1 = A+B \Rightarrow A = -1 - B \Rightarrow A = \frac{-5}{5} - \frac{-3}{5} \Rightarrow A=\frac{-8}{5}$
>
> $125 = A+C$

Where I did wrong in calculating of variable $A$, because correct answer is $A = \frac{-8}{25}$, but I get $A = \frac{-8}{5}$.

Comment: Are you using `=>` as an arrow, or as "greater than or equal"? For arrows, you can use `\Rightarrow`, that will produce $\Rightarrow$. For "greater than or equal", you should use `\geq`, which produces $\geq$.

Comment: The coefficient of $x$ is all wrong. You had $-5Ax+Bx$, and this became $-x(A+B)$; it should have been $x(B-5A)$.

Comment: thanks, i see now that missing -5A. it's time to stop math for today obvieously :)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** $\ $ It's simpler to use the [Heaviside cover-up method.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method) First, evaluating your $\rm\:E_2 = 2$nd equation at $\rm\:x = 0\:$ yields $\rm\:3 = -5\:b\:.\:$ Next, differentiating $\rm\:E_2\:$ and evaluating at $\rm\:x = 0\:$ yields $\rm\: 1 = b - 5\:a\:.$ Solve those for $\rm\:a,b\:$. Finally evaluating $\rm\:E_2\:$ at $\rm\:x=5\:$ yields $\rm\: 3133 = 25\:c\:.$

Answer (score 1):

From

$$\frac{125x^{2}+x+3}{x^{2}(x-5)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x^{2}}+\frac{C}{x-5}=
\frac{x(x-5)A+(x-5)B+x^{2}C}{x^{2}(x-5)}$$

it should be

$$125x^{2}+x+3=\left( A+C\right) x^{2}+\left( B-5A\right) x-5B$$

instead of

$$125x^{2}+x+3=\left( A+C\right) x^{2}+\left( A+B\right) x-5B.$$

Hence

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
3=-5B \\ 
1=B-5A \\ 
125=A+C
\end{array}
\Leftrightarrow \right. \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
B=-\frac{3}{5} \\ 
1=-\frac{3}{5}-5A \\ 
125=A+C
\end{array}
\Leftrightarrow \right. \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
B=-\frac{3}{5} \\ 
A=-\frac{8}{25} \\ 
C=\frac{3133}{25}
\end{array}
\right. $$

and the expansion into partial fractions is $$\frac{125x^{2}+x+3}{x^{2}(x-5)}=-\frac{8}{25x}-\frac{3}{5x^{2}}+\frac{3133}{25\left( x-5\right) }.$$

---

*Second method*. Multiply

$$\frac{125x^{2}+x+3}{x^{2}(x-5)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x^{2}}+\frac{C}{x-5}
\qquad (\ast )$$

by $x-5$

$$\frac{125x^{2}+x+3}{x^{2}}=\frac{A(x-5)}{x}+\frac{B(x-5)}{x^{2}}+C$$

and let $x\rightarrow 5$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 5}\frac{125x^{2}+5+3}{x^{2}}=\frac{3133}{25}=C.$$

Multiply $(\ast )$ by $x^{2}$

$$\frac{125x^{2}+x+3}{x-5}=Ax+B+\frac{x^{2}}{x-5}C$$

and let $x\rightarrow 0$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{125x^{2}+x+3}{x-5}=-\frac{3}{5}=B.$$

Substitute $C$ and $B$ in $(\ast )$

$$\frac{125x^{2}+x+3}{x^{2}(x-5)}=\frac{A}{x}-\frac{3}{5}\frac{1}{x^{2}}+
\frac{3133}{25}\frac{1}{x-5}$$

and set, say, $x=1$

$$-\frac{125+1+3}{4}=A-\frac{3}{5}-\frac{3133}{25}\frac{1}{4},$$

to find $A=-\dfrac{8}{25}$.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is of the form

**$$\frac{Ax + b}{ax^2 + bx + c} + \frac{C}{x + d}$$** i.e Product of quadratic and Linear Factors.

Keeping the above form in mind,this is what i did.

**$$\frac{125x^2 + x + 3}{x^2(x-5)} = \frac{Ax + B}{x^2} + \frac{C}{x-5}$$**

Look for a common denominator in RHS

**$$\frac{(Ax + B)(x - 5)}{x^2(x-5)} + \frac{c(x^2)}{(x-5)(x^2)}$$**
Adding the above fraction

**$$\frac{(Ax + B)(x - 5)+c(x^2)}{x^2(x - 5)}$$**

Now equating the numerator from LHS with the numerter obtained above {RHS} as the denominator of both LHS and RHS contain the same expression,you obtain,

**$$125x^2 + x + 3 = Ax^2 - 5Ax + Bx - 5B + cx^2$$**

Let A = 5,find out the value of C,I'am pretty sure even B would get lost.Obtain the value of B and C by choosing a suitable value for x.

I'am having difficuilty in determining the value of B and C,Let me know if you could.

Comment: $A$ cannot be $5$.